# jqGrid to html table conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I want to convert a HTML table into jqGrid and I am using the tabletoGrid() function when a "convert" button is clicked to achieve it. The data that is loaded onto the table is loaded dynamically. The first attempt to convert the table to grid works great but from the second attempt on the jqGrid doesnt load properly. I believe the solution is to convert the jqGrid back to table then load the data again and convert the table back to grid. Any idea on how to achieve this ?

Comment: please post all the relevant code. contrary to common belief, members of stackoverflow are not mind readers. unless we see your code, all you can get is a few guesses.

Answer (score 0):

It's very bad that you don't posted the code which you use. One have to guess what error you could made. I suppose that you missed the call of `GridUnload` to destroy the grid and to place empty `<table>` on the place. I can't point more exactly where you should place the call because I didn't seen your JavaScript code.